# For loop breaks an unrelated array

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Hey so I am using puppeteer and when I run this code:

```
console.log(dealsId[i]);

for (var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
    var refIdClasses = await sizes[i].$eval('input', a => a.getAttribute('class'));
    if (refIdClasses != 'disabled') {
        var refId = await sizes[i].$eval('input', a => a.getAttribute('value'));
        var size = await sizes[i].$eval('input', a => a.getAttribute('data-size'));
        refIds.push({ size: size, refId: refId });
    }
}
console.log(dealsId[i]);
```

The Deals Id works before the for loop and after the loop it says undefined and I am so confused on why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your for loop is also using `i` to iterate, possibly conflicting with the `i` in `dealsId[i]`.

Possible solution might be to change the variable in for loop from i to j.

The code becomes:

```
console.log(dealsId[i]);

for (var j = 0; j < sizes.length; j++) {
    var refIdClasses = await sizes[j].$eval('input', a => a.getAttribute('class'));
    if (refIdClasses != 'disabled') {
        var refId = await sizes[j].$eval('input', a => a.getAttribute('value'));
        var size = await sizes[j].$eval('input', a => a.getAttribute('data-size'));
        refIds.push({ size: size, refId: refId });
    }
}
console.log(dealsId[i]);
```

Comment: Yes, it's a possible solution, but a good solution is to use a `for...of` loop, that doesn't need a useless index variable at all.

Comment: Probably `sizes[i]` needs to be `sizes[j]`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you can revert the downvote :) i have edited the code for it

Answer (score 3):

Var `i` is globally-scoped, so by using `var i=0` you are definitely creating scope conflict. Use `let` or another variable name instead.

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem with `var`s. You can declare and re-declare them in the same scope without warning.

I assume you declared a `var i` in the code before what you showed, but you re-declare it in the `for` loop. `i < sizes.length` being the condition to break the loop, the loop break and `i` is now out-of-bounds of your array, hence the undefined (if `dealsId` has a size that's inferior to `sizes` array).

It isn't "unrelated" since you used the same variable to loop through 2 different arrays. Since we don't know if the two arrays have the exact same size, we can't pinpoint with 100% accuracy what's going on, but I'll go with that.